# Comparing outputs (list) of two functions returning wrong boolean

Tags: python, list, boolean

I wrote two functions `largest_number` and `largest_numbercopied` and ran a stress test to compare their results. Both of the functions output a rearranged version of the argument list. But thing is, when I run the stress test, I saw that even though both output lists are not the same (Not in the same order), the stress test is showing ok. Though I wrote to type ok only if `largest_number(a) == largest_numbercopied(a)`. Actually, I have faced a somewhat similar issue with this stress test function before with other algorithms, but those got fixed after a few trials, I don't know what is causing this problem.

```py
def maximum(m,n):
    m_=m
    n_=n
    if m<n:
        temp=m
        m=n
        n=temp
    
    if m==n:
        return 1
        
    mlist= []
    for i in range(len(str(m))):
        mlist.append(m//(10**(len(str(m))-1)))
        m= m % (10**(len(str(m))-1))
    
    nlist= []
    for i in range(len(str(n))):
        nlist.append(n//(10**(len(str(n))-1)))
        n= n % (10**(len(str(n))-1))
    
    digitlist= [mlist, nlist]
    
    if digitlist[0][0]==digitlist[1][0]:
        if len(digitlist[1])==1:
            if digitlist[0][1]>= digitlist[0][0]:
                res= 1
            
            else:
                res= 0
        else:
            if digitlist[0][1]==digitlist[1][1]:
                if digitlist[0][2]>=digitlist[0][1]:
                    res= 1
                else:
                    res= 0
            elif digitlist[0][1]>digitlist[1][1]:
                res= 1
            else:
                res= 0
        
    elif digitlist[0][0]>digitlist[1][0]:
        res= 1
    else:
        res= 0
    
    if m_<n_:
        if res==0:
            res=1
        else:
            res=0
    
    return res
def largest_number(a):
    a= sorted(a, reverse=True)
    res=""
    c=0
    while True:
        c=0
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if maximum(a[i],a[i+1])==0:
                c+=1
                idx=i
                #print(idx,c)
                break
        if c==0:
            break                
        temp= a[idx]
        a[idx]= a[idx+1]
        a[idx+1]= temp
        #print(a)

    return a

def IsGreaterOrEqual(digit, max_digit):
    return int(str(digit)+str(max_digit))>=int(str(max_digit)+str(digit))

def largest_numbercopied(lst):
    answer = []
    res=""
    while lst!=[]:
        max_digit = 0
        for digit in lst:
            if IsGreaterOrEqual(digit, max_digit):
                max_digit = digit
        answer.append(max_digit)
        lst.remove(max_digit)
    return answer
def stresstest():
    import random
    okcounter=0
    while True:
        n=random.randint(1,100)
        a=[]
        for i in range(n):
            a.append(random.randint(1,1000))
            
        print(f'numbers= {a}, Result1= {largest_number(a)}')
        print(f'numbers= {a}, Result2= {largest_numbercopied(a)}')

        if largest_number(a)== largest_numbercopied(a):
            okcounter= okcounter+1
            print('ok\n')
            if okcounter>=100:
                break

        else: 
            print('Error')
            break
            
stresstest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`largest_numbercopied` removes elements from `a`, but it's operating on the array that was passed in and not a copy of it. This means that your lines

```
print(f'numbers= {a}, Result1= {largest_number(a)}')
print(f'numbers= {a}, Result2= {largest_numbercopied(a)}')
```

will result in `a` being cleared out and then

```
if largest_number(a)== largest_numbercopied(a)
```

will be comparing the result of operating on an empty list.