# Two functions equality boolean not working properly in python

Tags: python, list, boolean

So I have been trying to stresstest for these two functions largest_number and largest_numbercopied. Both of them output a list of integers, but in the stresstest function I have written if largest_number(a)==largest_numbercopied(a) then print ok. But it is printing ok even if the two output lists are not equal.

```
def stresstest():
    import random
    okcounter=0
    while True:
        n=random.randint(1,100)
        a=[]
        for i in range(n):
            a.append(random.randint(1,1000))
        
        print(f'numbers= {a}\n')
        print(f'Result1= {largest_number(a)}\n')
        print(f'Result2= {largest_numbercopied(a)}')
        
        if largest_number(a)==largest_numbercopied(a):
            okcounter= okcounter+1
            print('ok\n')
            if okcounter>=100:
                break

        else: 
            print('Error')
            break
            
stresstest()
```

Comment: It's hard to say what could be wrong without seeing the methods or any output.

Comment: And you have not asked a question.

Comment: @Kemp I have shared the full code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088447/comparing-outputs-list-of-two-functions-returning-wrong-boolean